# how to display x,y,z coordinates in a TEXTBOX in C++ (KINECT SENSOR)

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and having a go at the kinect sensor  via C++ programming since i would be needing it for my studies later. i am trying to extract the X,Y,Z coordinates of the right hand from the skeletal viewer and display it in a textbox i have created. so far, i have been able to extract the x,y,z coordinates but displaying it in a textbox as been a challenge. it only displays some form of gibberish when i run the code but displays the text when i run the code without the kinect connected the way i programmed it to. so far, this is what have been able to do...

```
void dialog()
{
    if (check_kinect < 1)   // when the kinect isnt cnnected
        SetStatusMessage1(L"No Ready Kinect Found!");
    else             
       SetStatusMessage5(&RHx);
}



  void SetStatusMessage1(WCHAR * szMessage1)
    {
        SendDlgItemMessageW(m_hWnd, IDC_STATUS1, WM_SETTEXT, 0,(LPARAM)szMessage1);
    }
    void SetStatusMessage5(float* RHx)
    {
        SendDlgItemMessageW(m_hWnd, IDC_STATUS4, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)RHx);
    }
```

i am not sure if it is my use of pointers that is wrong or it is actually WM_SETTEXT that does not accept both float and int values.

Comment: So you convert `float` values to character representations before using `WM_SETTEXT`??

Comment: No, i haven't tried converting the float values to character representations. i just pass the values directly to the WM_SETTEXT.

Comment: That's a blatantly wrong approach (and should have been mentioned in the compiler warnings). Provide a proper textual representation to get a value presented in any visual control's primary text. That's no automatic conversion from numbers.

Comment: Removed [tag:kinect] tag, since there's no actual relation.

Comment: thanks, I will try doing that now.